# Elastic search node has too many connections

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ES cluster with 4 nodes setup behind haproxy. currently one of the node is sending notification that ES connection is more than 1000. I checked the total number of ES connections using the following command `sudo lsof -nPi tcp:9200 | awk {'print $2'} |sort | uniq -c | sort | grep [0-9]` and it shows there are 1064 connections to the port 9200 and it is more when compared to other nodes in the clsuter.Does 1064 include only Established connection or other connections as well? When checked for the IPs which has too many connection to ES node, one of the haproxy loadbalancerver has 130 connections to this cluster. Could anyone please help me how do i check what is making so many connections to this node in the ES cluster

Comment: can you give output of : curl 'ip_es:9200/_cat/health?v'   also take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html. Note that elastic est nothing but a rest API (http so), so on server side, we cant talk about "connection".

Comment: i am using collectd +logstash+elasticsearch+elastalert. There is `tcpconn` plugin enabled in collectd configuration and the same plugin is called in elastert yaml file as below, It is related to tcp connection to the port 9200 which is more than 1100. Please correct me if I am wrong                                                   `filter:
- query:
    match:
      plugin: "tcpconns"`